# Optimize this loss function (any way to vectorize it?)

Tags: numpy, loss-function

> ```
> def get_model_score(preds, actuals, sw):
>     total_loss = 0
>     for i in range(len(preds)):
>         for idx, v in enumerate(actuals[i]):
>             if v != 0:
>                 total_loss += sw[i] * abs(preds[i][idx] - actuals[i][idx])
>
>     loss = total_loss / (sum(sw) * len(preds))
>
>     return loss
> ```

I have a loss function which essentially is a weighted absolute mean error. However, we can expect every "true" sample to only have one non-zero value ex. [0, 0, 1]. We only want to account for the loss between this non-zero value and the corresponding predicted value.

Take the following examples:

```
True: [0, 0, 1]

Predicted: [0.5, -0.5, 0.5]
```

The loss for this sample would simply just be 0.5. (In the actual function though we do also have an array of sample-wise weights as well- "sw")

That being said I'm having trouble figuring out if my function can be vectorized and put into Numpy.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is what did the trick

```
> np.sum(np.abs(actuals[~np.isnan(actuals)] - preds[~np.isnan(actuals)])
> * sw) / (sum(sw) * len(preds))
```

Actually ended up going with nulls instead of zeros so the condition is `~np.isnan(actuals)`.

But yea, I think the trick was the use the condition on both the actual and pred array. On the pred array it will grab the correct index based on the condition from the actual array. If this helps for anyone doing something similar.